# How to use In Operator for Integers?

Tags: python

everyone. Today I saw a code to create a 4-digit bulls and cows game. But I am curious if anyone can explain to me how did user_guess in numbers work at line 12? From what I understand, number is a string and user_guess is an integer which shouldn't work right? The code is below.

```
import random
secret_number = str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
print("Guess the number. It contains 4 digits.")

remaining_try = 7

def get_bulls_cows(number, user_guess):
 bulls_cows = [0,0] #cows, then bulls
 for i in range(len(number)):
    if user_guess[i] == number[i]:
        bulls_cows[0] += 1
    elif user_guess[i] in number:
        bulls_cows[1] += 1
return bulls_cows

while remaining_try > 0:
player_guess = input("Enter your guess: ")

if player_guess == secret_number:
    print("Yay, you guessed it!")
    print("YOU WIN.")
    break
else:
    bulls_cows = get_bulls_cows(secret_number,player_guess)
  
    print("Bulls: ",bulls_cows[0])
    print("Cows: ",bulls_cows[1])

    remaining_try -= 1

    if remaining_try < 1:
        print("You lost the game.")
        break
```

Comment: `number` and `user_guess` are both strings. Also your code is unrunnable and does not make sense because it is not properly indented.

Comment: The `user_guess` variable is a parameter of the `get_bulls_cows()` function which is supplied with that parameter from the variable `player_guess` which is the return value of `input("Enter your guess: ")` which always returns a string.

Comment: `number` is a string, `in` for strings works by checking if something is a substring of it. `player_guess` is assigned return value from `input`, which is a string.

Comment: @khelwood Hey, sorry. I copy pasted this so the indents might have been ruined a little bit. But it works after the indents are fixed.

Comment: @quamrana Hey, thanks for the reply.  But if I put numbers in it, will it still be considered a string though? I thought it would be considered as an integer.

Comment: `"numbers in it"` <- what does that mean? btw the `input()` function *always* returns a string, even if there are numeric digits in it.

Comment: "*it works after the indents are fixed*"—So [edit] your code and fix them.

Comment: @quamrana I see, that settles my question then, thanks for you answer and clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

If the user inputs numbers, the player_guess variable will be treated as a string. In Python, the input function always returns a string, regardless of what the user enters.

So, in the context of your code, when the user inputs a numerical value, it will be stored as a string in the player_guess variable. Therefore, treating it as a string in the get_bulls_cows function is correct, and the code should work as expected.

Nonetheless, here's a modified version of the code that ensures user_guess is treated as a string:

```
import random

secret_number = str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
print("Guess the number. It contains 4 digits.")

remaining_try = 7

def get_bulls_cows(number, user_guess):
    bulls_cows = [0, 0]  # cows, then bulls
    for i in range(len(number)):
        if user_guess[i] == number[i]:
            bulls_cows[0] += 1
        elif user_guess[i] in number:
            bulls_cows[1] += 1
    return bulls_cows

while remaining_try > 0:
    player_guess = input("Enter your guess: ")

    if player_guess == secret_number:
        print("Yay, you guessed it!")
        print("YOU WIN.")
        break
    else:
        bulls_cows = get_bulls_cows(secret_number, player_guess)
  
        print("Bulls: ", bulls_cows[0])
        print("Cows: ", bulls_cows[1])

        remaining_try -= 1

        if remaining_try < 1:
            print("You lost the game.")
            break
```

Now, player_guess is treated as a string, and the code should work as intended.